# Gradle: DSL method not found: minSdkVersion / targetSdkVersion / compileSdkVersion / buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, gradle, dsl, android-gradle-2.2

As it took me some time to find the solution for this error, I post my problem and solution here in the hope that I find it next time faster:

> Error:(39, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'minSdkVersion()'

**What I tried to do:**

- I followed the [Android Test Blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint)'s sample to define the library versions in the top level / rootProject'S build.gradle file:

  ext {
    minSdkVersion 16
  }
- And wanted to use it in the app's/module's build.gradle file:

  minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion

Answer (score 9):

After half an hour or so I notices that this was a simple typo -.-

**Solution**

Add the "=" sign when you define a variable, else, Gradle thinks you call an Android method which it does not yet know in the top level build file:

```
ext { minSdkVersion = 16 }
```